# facebook api doesn't retrieve email and birthday

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, symfony1, facebook-login

I use facebook sdk api with symfony, in the below $user_profile array he can retrieve every information but email and birthday.

```
        require 'facebook.php';
        $app_id = sfConfig::get('app_facebook_app_id');
        $app_secret = sfConfig::get('app_facebook_secret_key');
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => $app_id,
            'secret' => $app_secret,
            ));
        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        if ($user) {
              try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
        }
       if ($user) {        
           $location= $user_profile['location']['name'];
           $gender = $user_profile['gender'];
            $user_info = array(
                'uid' => $user_profile['id'],
                'first_name' => $user_profile['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $user_profile['last_name'],
                'email' => $user_profile['email'],
                'birthday' => $user_profile['birthday'],
                'gender' => $user_profile['gender'],
            );
```

when I use `print_r($user_profile)` it return:

```
Array ( 
  [uid] => 100004246655890 
  [first_name] => Ala 
  [last_name] => Hamad 
  [email] => 
  [birthday] => 
  [gender] => male 
)
```

the email and birthday empty.

Answer (score 3):

Nowhere in your code does it appear that you're requesting the [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) needed to access the user's email address or birthday

Check the permissions doc and make sure you're requesting the `email` and `user_birthday` permissions in your [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) code.

Comment: thank  you after your answer I searched for how to write that in code, then I found that I have to request email permission within the scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't receive these information, one of the cause is because the user configuration prohibits sharing them and Facebook don't send the warns.

Because some users, in the configuration, prohibits sharing the email or other information.

Comment: yes it retrieve email from some users but some other users not

Answer (score 0):

I searched for how to write that in code, then I found that I have to request email permission within the scope in the login url:

```
$params = array(
  'redirect_uri' => url_for('sfGuardAuth/loginWithFB', true),'scope' => 'email,user_birthday,user_location'
);
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```